# Issues importing libraries

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, environment-variables

I just installed Python and Visual Studio code on a Windows 10 machine.

I have imported i few libraries using pip. When I did that I got a warning saying I needed to add a certain folder to PATH which I did.

Using the cdm, I can start a python environment and import matplotlib without issues. I note that my Python version in the cmd is Python 3.9.7

When doing the same thing in Visual Studio code I get the following error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I also notice that my Pyhton version in Visual Studio Code is Pyhton 3.9.1.

I dont really understand what is going on here since I've never had this issue before. Usually it "just works"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 versions of python installed.  One of them could be a virtual environment.  You can diagnose which Python interpreter you are using by running:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

If VSCode you can switch between interpreters; it may take some searching through the options.

Answer (score 0):

In to the visual code terminal, which probably is using your venv (you should see "*(venv)*" at begin of each row) type:

```
pip list
```

and look if you module is installed. Otherwise you can install here or change environment.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed in two python versions **Python 3.9.7** and **Python 3.9.1** in vs code.**Matplotlib** was installed in **Python 3.9.7** in vscode, but you used **python3.9.1** as an interpreter, that’s why it threw No module error. You need to add a virtual environment of Python 3.9.1. Python has a full guide here on how to set virtual environment [How to add virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

then you change python interpreter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` has been installed in the `python 3.9.7` while not in the `python 3.9.1`.

So you can try to switch the python version in the VSCode to the `python 3.9.7` or install the `matplotlib` in the `python 3.9.1`.

You can click here to switch the environment. And you can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) for more methods and details.

[image]

Or you can install the `matplotlib` package again in the VSCode terminal.